# HorizontalListView inside a ScrollView within fragments in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

In my application I have a scenario where I have to show different products inside a viewpager. In each product I show a pic and when the user does a fling action on the photo scrollview translates and covers the photo. Now for showing the related items I have to use HorizontalListview. But what happens is ,when I start scrolling the HorizontalListView for the first time it scrolls but the second touch is passed to the ViewPager i.e. alternate touches work. Can someone suggest me a better way of showing horizontal items in my case. 
Thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Disable images' scroll, enlarge the image on click and show scroll. Else keep focus on listview.

I think facebook app also does same (keep images out of focus until clicked on)